# PayPal fsockopen error in my log file

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am developing my site in core php. Some days before my PayPal payment gateway working fine. But from yesterday it is not working. I am getting following error  -

Here is complete PayPal sandbox log file -

```
[01/25/2016 12:03 AM] - FAIL: fsockopen error no. 0: !
[From:ipn.sandbox.paypal.com|173.0.82.126]IPN POST Vars Received By Paypal_IPN Response API:
mc_gross=40.00 
protection_eligibility=Ineligible 
address_status=unconfirmed 
payer_id=FUD45KJ4NRVMU 
tax=0.00 
address_street=abcd
abcd 
payment_date=23:03:24 Jan 24, 2016 PST 
payment_status=Pending 
charset=windows-1252 
address_zip=751010 
first_name=sanjib 
address_country_code=IN 
address_name=sanjib prahdna 
notify_version=3.8 
custom= 
payer_status=verified 
address_country=India 
address_city=bbsr 
quantity=2 
verify_sign=AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAsRnYoKnR7..YqYLMh4beV87aSZu 
payer_email=psanjibttu@gmail.com 
txn_id=3XU94274J66816604 
payment_type=instant 
last_name=prahdna 
address_state=Orissa 
receiver_email=chinmaysahu235@yahoo.com 
pending_reason=unilateral 
txn_type=web_accept 
item_name=Ceili Rain 
mc_currency=USD 
item_number= 
residence_country=IN 
test_ipn=1 
handling_amount=0.00 
transaction_subject= 
payment_gross=40.00 
shipping=0.00 
ipn_track_id=aa4fb80956e9 
IPN Response from Paypal Server:
```

Please help me and tell me what is the main reason behind it?

Comment: can you post your code? I have been attempting to get PayPal IPN with fsock working for days but it just hangs there.

Comment: @Tsukasa please wait... I am uploading my code here

Comment: @Tsukasa please download code here - http://learnphp.in/paypal_test/paypal_test.zip

Comment: I got my code working. Take a look at Update 2. The only issue I have now is that $res is always empty. Not sure if this is because i'm testing in sandbox or not. Maybe you can help answer that one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34958560/974840

Comment: I have checked this script in different server. This is working fine.